# Maximality of orthonormal bases

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

For a Hilbert space $\cal{H}$, what is the easiest way to see that an orthonormal basis $B$, for $\cal{H}$ is **maximal**, that is, that for any other orthonormal basis $B'$, we have $B \subseteq B'$ if and only if $B = B'$?

Comment: Well, what do you know about the cardinality of bases for a vector space?

Comment: @Rellek Not particularly useful, considering that an infinite set can have a proper subset of the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $B \subset B'$, where the containment is proper. Choose $b \in B' \backslash B$; by definition of orthonormal basis, $\langle b , c \rangle = 0$ for all $c \in B$. By maximality, $b = 0$, which is a contradiction.